# Disallow creating document with specific field when other field has specific value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema

```js
const mySchema = new Schema({
  delta: { type: Number, required: function() { return this.operation === 'change' } },
  operation: { type: String, enum: ['change', 'scan'], required: true }
}];
```

I want `delta` field to be in the document only when `operation` has value of `'change'`.

When `operation` has value of `'scan'` the document must not have `delta`.

Is there a way to achieve via schema definition, without using hooks?

Comment: It can be achieved using the MongoDB Schema Validation (and I dont know if such feature is available with Mongoose).

Comment: @prasad_ It seems the only solution is to use pre save hook. Thanks for answering =)